# Tumblr blog under subdomain blog.mysite.com - do I still get the benefit?

Tags: google, subdomain, backlinks, tumblr

I've got a Tumblr blog for my main site, I use it more as a proper blog with articles and images, rather than just a tumblog.

The blog is mapped to `blog.mydomain.com`.

Becuase of the ease of *social* reposting in Tumblr people often repost my articles (which is great - backlinks!) But all these links go back to my blog and not my main site which is a `mydomain.com` does Google see `blog.mydomain` and `mydomain` as the same / linked item and is my main site getting the benefit of these links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sub domain is treated as a different entity. If you're linking from say your blog to your root domain you will see a benefit with the more trust value you build up to your blog.